# Use a form created in vba in the moment of creation

Tags: vba, powerpoint, userform

I created a form in VBA programatically. I did that because first I use another form and depending on the value I set in this first form I have to make the other one bigger or smaller.

I need to use this form just when I click a button for the first one. It appears and I can write text on the textboxes... but when I click on the button of the second form (The one that I did programmatically) I have to take that text that I wrote but I check with MsgBox to see the value and it seems to be empty (I cannot debug it because is a code that is created while the process is already start). If I exec this again (because now it is stored as a normal form) the values that I write appears.

How can I make to take the values in the first time I exec it?

Here is the code that I create to do it.

```
       'Create the UserForm
        Set TempForm = ActivePresentation.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)


        'Set Properties for TempForm
        With TempForm
            .Properties("Caption") = "Possible answers"
            .Properties("Width") = 300
            .Properties("Height") = 10 + 34 * choiceNum + 50
        End With
        FormName = TempForm.Name

        For i = 1 To choiceNum

            Set newTab = TempForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "label" & i, True)
            With newTab
                .Caption = "Answer" & i
                .width = 40
                .height = 15
                .top = 10 + 30 * (i - 1)
                .left = 10
            End With

            Set cCntrl = TempForm.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "textBox" & i, True)
            With cCntrl
                .width = 150
                .height = 15
                .top = 10 + 30 * (i - 1)
                .left = 60
                .ZOrder (0)
            End With
        Next i

        Set NewButton = TempForm.Designer.Controls.Add("forms.CommandButton.1", "answerButton", True)
        With NewButton
            .Caption = "Create survey"
            .left = 60
            .top = 30 * choiceNum + 10
        End With
        'X = ActivePresentation.VBProject.VBComponents(FormName).CodeModule.CountOfLines
        With TempForm.CodeModule
          X = .CountOfLines + 1
            .InsertLines X + 1, "Sub answerButton_Click()"
            .InsertLines X + 2, "   Dim cSlide As Slide"
            .InsertLines X + 3, "  Dim survey As Shape"
            .InsertLines X + 4, "  Dim top As Integer"
            .InsertLines X + 5, "   Set cSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide"
            .InsertLines X + 6, "   top = 30"
            .InsertLines X + 7, "   "
            .InsertLines X + 8, "   For i = 1 To surveyCreation.choNum"
            .InsertLines X + 9, "   "
            .InsertLines X + 10, "   top = top + 15"
            .InsertLines X + 11, "   Set survey = cSlide.Shapes.AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, 30, top, 400, 10)"
            .InsertLines X + 12, "   survey.TextFrame.TextRange.text = UserForm1.Controls(i * 2 - 1).Text"
            .InsertLines X + 13, "   MsgBox ""this is the result: "" & UserForm1.Controls(i * 2 - 1).Text"
            .InsertLines X + 14, "   survey.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet = True"
            .InsertLines X + 15, "   survey.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type = ppBulletUnnumbered"
            .InsertLines X + 16, "  survey.Select Replace:=False"
            .InsertLines X + 17, "  Next i"
            .InsertLines X + 18, "  With ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange"
            .InsertLines X + 19, "  .Group.title = ""Dink survey creation"" & surveyCreation.typ"
            .InsertLines X + 20, "End With"
            .InsertLines X + 21, "End Sub"
        End With

       VBA.UserForms.Add(FormName).Show
```

Hope that I explain myself well.

Comment: Why are you using `UserForm1` in `UserForm1.Controls(i * 2 - 1).Text`? Every time you add a form, it will have a different name. Try this `Me.Controls(i * 2 - 1).Text`

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. I was using UserForm1 because that was the name created by default and when you exec the form again it was working so this was the name but maybe in the time of creation the name is not set by default yet. Anyway is solved now! :)